# Grease Pencil stroke thickness proportional editing doesn't work

Tags: grease-pencil

basically, Just started using the Grease pencil and I want to add some outlines to a logo ...

problem : I add a stroke and I want to make a smooth transition between thick and thin along the stroke, so I add an arc stroke, go into edit mode and I can edit the thickness of individual vertices but when I go to proportional editing : OH, NO, no matter how far I scroll the falloff circle, it will always edit the thickness of the entire curve (I'm decently sure nothing is wrong with my file and I just accidentally activated some setting that does this)

[image: what happens when I use prop edit mode]

file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oz_8H4qpYjc6P2FN-caK9Jk_dH2rhE_-